# Implementing collision detection python script on dronekit

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit-android

We're building off of the Tower app, which was built with dronekit-android, and flying the 3dr solo with it.  We're thinking about adding some sort of collision detection with it.

Is it feasible to run some python script on the drone, basically reading some IR or ultrasound sensor via the accessory bay, and basically yell at the Android tablet when it detects something?  That way, the tablet will tell the drone to fly backwards or something.

Otherwise, would we use the dronekit-python libs to do that?  How would use a tablet / computer to have a Tower-like functionality with that?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: can you ping the developers on the gitter channel @ https://gitter.im/dronekit/dronekit-android to go over the functionality you're trying to accomplish.